# For each not working for the json data

Tags: jquery, .net, json, foreach

I have following json data,

```
{"Key":"ar-SA","Value":"Arabic - Saudi Arabia","Key":"zh-HK","Value":"Chinese - Hong Kong SAR","Key":"zh-SG","Value":"Chinese - Singapore","Key":"en-AU","Value":"English - Australia","Key":"en-AT","Value":"English - Austria","Key":"en-BO","Value":"English - Botswana"}
```

But for each is not working using the below code:

Execution not entering in for each statement:

```
 function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
    var ddItems = data.d;

     $.each(ddItems, function (index, ddItem) {
                    alert('key ' + ddItem.Key);
                    alert('value ' + ddItem.Value);
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two arguments to `$.each()` function are the key and the value respectively, see

```js
var ddItems = {"Key":"ar-SA","Value":"Arabic - Saudi Arabia","Key":"zh-HK","Value":"Chinese - Hong Kong SAR","Key":"zh-SG","Value":"Chinese - Singapore","Key":"en-AU","Value":"English - Australia","Key":"en-AT","Value":"English - Austria","Key":"en-BO","Value":"English - Botswana"}

 function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
$.each(data, function (key, ddItem) {
                    console.log('key ' + key);
                    console.log('value ' + ddItem);
                });
                
 }
 
 fnsuccesscallback(ddItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: console.log(data.d) to see if the you are having the same data that you posted. In my answer I assumed, that ddItems is the data that you posted, if not then use $.each over data, also make sure you are calling the function

Comment: can u add a fiddler?

Comment: its not entering the for each loop

Comment: I have added the snippet, see it

Comment: why only one loop is running ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {"Key":"ar-SA","Value":"Arabic - Saudi Arabia","Key":"zh-HK","Value":"Chinese - Hong Kong SAR","Key":"zh-SG","Value":"Chinese - Singapore","Key":"en-AU","Value":"English - Australia","Key":"en-AT","Value":"English - Austria","Key":"en-BO","Value":"English - Botswana"}



$.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    alert('key ' + key);
                    alert('value ' + value);
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why only one loop is running

Comment: Because you have same key value 'Key'. Hence, only last value would be coming in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string was not in correct format,Correct this and try this code

```
$.parseJSON(Your json string)
```

Its will convert string in array and you can easily loop throw each row

Comment: can u add a fiddler please